# Typescript make 1 convert function for multiple type (number, vector, size etc...)

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create 1 convert function for varius type(number, vector, size, ...).

But typescript get compile error at return line on my code.

Did I use wrong way for generic? I cannot find my mistake.

```
type ConvertType = "Centimeter" | "Meter" | "Radian" | "Degree"

const DEG2RAD = Math.PI / 180
const RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI

export function convertTo<T extends number | Vector3 | Size>(type: ConvertType, arg: T) {
    let multiply

    switch (type) {
        case "Centimeter":
            multiply = 100
            break
        case "Meter":
            multiply = 0.01
            break
        case "Radian":
            multiply = DEG2RAD
            break
        case "Degree":
            multiply = RAD2DEG
            break
    }

    return (typeof arg === "number" ?
        arg * multiply : multiplyObject<T>(arg, multiply))
}

function multiplyObjectType<T extends Vector3 | Size>(arg: T, multiply: number) {
    const result = {} as Vector3 | Size

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arg)) {
        result[key] = value * multiply
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: please provide reproducable example

Answer (score 0):

While it's not completely clear what error exactly you're getting. This pattern is quite common and I guess the error is something like:

```
Type 'number | Vector3 | Size' is not assignable to type 'Size'.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Size'.
```

The problem is typescript is unable to narrow the type of *generic type parameter* `T extends number | Vector3 | Size`. In good details the issue is discussed here [microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). And in the shape more similar to your question here [microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995). There are some workarounds mentioned in those threads you may select from.

Though if you're not going to use `T extends` feature and is expecting the functions to accept only concrete types you may get rid of *type parameter* and rewrite your code as follows:

```ts
export function convertTo(type: ConvertType, arg: number): number
export function convertTo(type: ConvertType, arg: Vector3): Vector3
export function convertTo(type: ConvertType, arg: Size): Size
export function convertTo(type: ConvertType, arg: number | Vector3 | Size) {
    let multiply

    switch (type) {
        case "Centimeter":
            multiply = 100
            break
        case "Meter":
            multiply = 0.01
            break
        case "Radian":
            multiply = DEG2RAD
            break
        case "Degree":
            multiply = RAD2DEG
            break
    }

    return (typeof arg === "number") ? arg * multiply : multiplyObject(arg, multiply)
}

function multiplyObject<T extends Vector3 | Size>(arg: T, multiply: number): T {
    const result = {} as T

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arg)) {
        result[key] = value * multiply
    }

    return result
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBzanN)

Comment: Thanks for declaration. I choose overload.